# Visual Basic infopath print button XDocument not declared

Tags: infopath, printing, vba

I have an InfoPath form where I am trying to add a print button and add visual basic to print the form.
What I have done so far:

1) Add a button to the form

2) in button properties `click edit form code...`

3) The code is as follows :

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.InfoPath
Imports System
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.XPath


Namespace Performance_and_Development_121_form

    Public Class FormCode

        ' Member variables are not supported in browser-enabled forms.
        ' Instead, write and read these values from the FormState
        ' dictionary using code such as the following:
        '
        ' Private Property _memberVariable() As Object
        '     Get
        '         _memberVariable = FormState("_memberVariable")
        '     End Get
        '     Set
        '         FormState("_memberVariable") = value
        '     End Set
        ' End Property

        ' NOTE: The following procedure is required by Microsoft InfoPath.
        ' It can be modified using Microsoft InfoPath.
        Private Sub InternalStartup(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Startup
            AddHandler DirectCast(EventManager.ControlEvents("CTRL97_60"), ButtonEvent).Clicked, AddressOf CTRL97_60_Clicked

            AddHandler DirectCast(EventManager.ControlEvents("PrintForm"), ButtonEvent).Clicked, AddressOf PrintForm_Clicked
        End Sub




        Public Sub PrintForm_Clicked(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ClickedEventArgs)
            XDocument.PrintOut()
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

The only thing I added was `XDocument.PrintOut()` the rest was generate already.
I am getting an error saying `XDocument is not declared`, this is the same when I add `thisXDocument`
I am using InfoPath 2010 and Visual basic

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the answer [here](http://www.infopathdev.com/forums/p/20682/99572.aspx):

> `XDocument` is only available in the 2003 object model.  In 2007 and 2010, you would use `this.Print();`